# How to configure two Ubuntu servers in a LAN

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, load-balancer

I have been running a Kubuntu 22.04 server on my LAN for some time. It runs on Apache with domains, a mail server for two domains, on Nextcloud and Jellyfin domains, Samba locally for LAN sharing. I want to operate a different Ubuntu server 22.04, managed only via SSH, for now I want to run AdGuarHome, LAMP on it, but separately installed services where one domain will run for remote management via WebUI (Webmin...) + some subdomains for individual services, but I don't know how get it going. Or Nginx as a proxy server, I just can't configure it to work like me. I have the ports forwarded to the first server, and how should I start the HTTP and HTTPS services on the second server, if there is a problem with the ports after installing AGH? Can someone advise me how to set up Proxy, Reverse Proxy, LaodBalancer and similar. I did not use these settings, since the pages are not indexed in search engines, more or less these services are for private use. But I can't set it up with two servers.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.